# error element not visible because its ancestor has position: fixed CSS property and it is overflowed by other element

Tags: cypress

[image]i am trying to click on the icon trash

```html
<div class="form-body">
  <div class="infos">
    <div class="recap">
      <div class="form-actions ">
        <a class="btn btn-light btn-icon btn-icon-light" title="download" href=""
          target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" download="my_file">
          <i class="icon-download"></i>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-icon btn-icon-light" title="delete">
          <i class="icon-trash">
```

i have tried

```
cy.get('i.icon-trash').click()
cy.get(.form-actions .icon-trash').click()
```

Whatever i am trying i am getting the error:

> The element <i.icon-trash> is not visible because its ancestor has position: fixed CSS property and it is overflowed by other elements. How about scrolling to the element with cy.scrollIntoView()?
>
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

scrollIntoView() also is not working.
Does anyone know why this error is happening please?

Thank you
screenshot of the html part above

Comment: Have you tried using `cy.get('i.icon-trash').click({force: true})`? The error message is pretty clear about what is happening, and without giving us more HTML and a screenshot, we probably won't be able to solve your issue.

Comment: i  have added an image for the html can you pls check.
Also i dont want to use force as its like a hack..

Comment: Can you add an image of the website when Cypress fails? At the moment, if you can't scroll the element into view, and the element is visible, I can't think of another workaround beyond adding `{force: true}`

Comment: The trash button is visible on the UI but it keeps saying this when
i tried clicking the data test id :
 <btn btn-light btn-icon btn-icon-light> is not visible because its ancestor has position: fixed CSS property and it is overflowed by other elements. How about scrolling to the element with cy.scrollIntoView()?

Comment: sorry cannot send sscrrenshot as it has confidential info but if you were to click on that button with the DOM i have given how you would have done it please..
maybe another approach can help

Comment: I'm still thinking your best bet is going to be to try `{force: true}` and use it if it works. Yes, it isn't the best way to handle this, but if it works, it is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The button parent of the icon has the click handler, try clicking that

```js
cy.get('i.icon-trash')
  .parent()
  .scrollIntoView()     
  .should('be.visible')   // for good measure, may not require
  .click()
```

but I suspect the problem still persists.

Also try [realClick()](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealclick)

```js
cy.get('i.icon-trash')
  .parent()
  .scrollIntoView()     
  .should('be.visible')   
  .realClick({ position: "topLeft" })  // try various click positions
```

---

You can also try setting a larger viewport at the top of the test.

---

Other than that try working the CSS - but this is a bit of a hack.

Arguably it's ok because you are testing the click logic not the visibility of the icon (also true for `.click({force:true})`).

Identify the element with `position: fixed` for example if it's `div.form-actions`

```js
cy.get('div.form-actions')
  .then($formActions => {
    $formActions.css({ position: 'relative' })
  })
```